# How to generate a session token in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, session, authentication, spring-boot, session-cookies

I have a spring-boot back end for a Sencha Touch app and am trying to make a token-based login system. What is the simplest way to do so? I am a newbie and have never done back-end coding before. How do I generate a session-token in Spring Boot?

Comment: Do you mean by finding a session? I know how to do it in spring MVC but not spring-boot. Is there a lot of difference? Also, can you elaborate on the token-based login system a bit further?

Comment: What sort of token are you talking about? JWT? OAuth2? Just a session cookie?

Comment: @OneRaynyDay Spring Boot is just a toolset for easy configuration of Spring applications. You still use Spring MVC and the other components, you just don't have to deal with all of the boilerplate configuration.

Comment: Is it a REST/SOAP backend or is there some view concept on the backend?  Do you have a DB or cache for storing logins and Tokens on the backend?

Comment: I am trying to get my app to identify users when they log in so it can display their information. What I have so far for the rest of the app is a RESTful API. There is an embedded HSQLDB where I am storing user credentials but I am not sure how to generate tokens and where to keep them.